# Problems receiving NSNotification when using popToRootViewControllerAnimated

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsnotification

I have a `UIViewController` where the user clicks a button and then they go onto another `UIViewController` to do some image manipulation. Once the image has been manipulated I want a `NSNotification`.

My problem as it stands out is that I am not receiving the `NSNotification` in the first `UIViewController` when the user finished cropping the image `- (void) finishCropping`... I covered all my grounds and put the notification handling method in `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear`, `viewWillAppear`...

I dont understand why I am not receiving the notification? This should be quite straight forward

If i comment out the `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];` from `viewDidDisappear` it works.... but theoretically speaking... if I am re setting the notification handlers, they should be called again in any of the 3 available methods?

**First UIViewController & NSNotification Receiver**

```
- (void) addNewPictureFromLibrary {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];

    imageCroppingViewController* popupController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"imageCroppingView2"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:popupController animated:YES];

}
- (void) viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated    {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [self notifications];
}
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self notifications];
}
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
     [self notifications];
}
    - (void) notifications {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
         addObserver:self
         selector:@selector(imageCroppingView:)
         name:@"imageCroppingView"
         object:nil];
    }
- (void) imageCroppingView:(NSNotification *) notification {
    NSLog(@"imageCroppingView IN HERE");
}
```

**Sender UIViewController**

```
- (void) finishCropping {
    float zoomScale = 1.0 / [scrollView zoomScale];
    CGRect visibleRect;
    visibleRect.origin.x = scrollView.contentOffset.x * zoomScale;
    visibleRect.origin.y = scrollView.contentOffset.y * zoomScale;
    visibleRect.size.width = scrollView.bounds.size.width * zoomScale;
    visibleRect.size.height = scrollView.bounds.size.height * zoomScale;

    UIImage *cropped = imageFromView(imageView.image, &visibleRect);
    NSDictionary *dictionary = @{@"image":cropped};

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = NO;
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:TRUE];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     postNotificationName:@"imageCroppingView"
     object:nil
     userInfo:dictionary];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are removing `self` from `NSNotificationCenter` in viewDidDisappear .
When another view is loaded `viewDidDisappear` is called automatically on to your existing view controller and hence it de-regsiter itself for all the notifications because of this code in your first UIViewController -

```
- (void) viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated    {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

`viewDidDisappear` is the last method to be called before imageCroppingViewController is loaded and thereafter you never register.

If you want to selectively de-register for some notifications then call `removeObserver` with name method of `NSNotificationCenter`

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"NotificationNameYouDontWantToListenAnyLonger" object:nil];
```

Please note calling `addObserver` for a notification multiple time doesn't mean you registered for those many times. Object would have only one entry in notification center *per notification* (loosely speaking unique objects per notification name).

I hope this clarifies and take you towards solution. Let me know if any questions.

Comment: Yes, I get that I am removing the Observer at `viewDidDisappear`. but I need to removeObserver and thats the best place to unregister them... The issue is that I am also registering the observers at `viewWillAppear` that gets called after `popToRootViewControllerAnimated` but not soon enough to get the passed NSNoficiation.

Comment: You can simply register the observer in `viewDidLoad` and removeObserver (de-register) in `dealloc` method of the view controller - It means the controller would listen the notification as long as it's alive (even when the view is not visible). Another option is register & de-register in `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidDisapper` respectively - It means the view controller would listen the notification only when visible (on screen).

Comment: U have no dealloc method.

Comment: A class still have dealloc (even post Automatic Reference Counting introduction) but can't call dealloc on any object now. It is used typically for such cleanup work only. I recommend you read "ARC Enforces New Rules" (first 3 bullet points) at this link - https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html